# Why is two-photon absorption a third-order non-linear process?

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics

I've just started learning about non-linear optics where I could not understand why the **two photon** absorption is a $\chi^{(3)}$ process. The way I understand susceptibility is that the order of $\chi$ tells us the number of frequencies added/subtracted(not a precise defn.), while the real/imaginary part tell us if it's corresponding to the phase/absorption. So if in TPA only two photons are absorbed, why is it not described by imaginary part of $\chi^{(2)}$ ?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually rather confusing.  So, good question!

This describes single-photon interaction with a material:
$$
\mathbf{P}=\chi^{(1)}\mathbf{E}
$$
Or rewritten to assume time-harmonic fields,
$$
P_ie^{i \omega_1 t}=\chi^{(1)}_{ij}E_je^{i \omega_1 t}
$$
All of the subscripts refer to the spatial components of the field polarization, making $\chi^{(1)}_{ij}$ a tensor describing the material response.

So $\chi^{(1)}$ is taking in the frequency $\omega_1$ (or energy = $\hbar\omega_1$) and generating a material polarization oscillating with the same frequency.  This can be alternately expressed in terms of photon energy conservation as $\chi^{(1)}(\omega_1=\omega_1)$ or $\chi^{(1)}(0=\omega_1-\omega_1)$.  And, as you rightly point out, the imaginary component of $\chi$ corresponds to absorption.  In the absence of absorption, this process can represent a coherent promotion of an electron from the ground state to an excited state and back down again, continually.

But *power flow* for EM waves is determined by the Poynting vector, $\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{H}$.  Since power is proportional to the number of photons, you can think of a photon as needing two factors of field.  So to add another photon to the existing single-photon interaction, you need to multiply by two more fields and use $\chi^{(3)}$:
$$
P_ie^{i \omega_1 t}=\chi^{(3)}_{ijkl}E_je^{i \omega_1 t}E_ke^{i \omega_2 t}E_le^{-i \omega_2 t}
$$

The energy conservation of this process can be expressed as $\chi^{(3)}(\omega_1=\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_2)$ or $\chi^{(3)}(0=\omega_1-\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_2)$.  Again, $\chi^{(3)}$ is generally complex, to support absorption and phase shift.  The choice of two distinct frequencies reflects the two colors of the photons for two-photon absorption.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate the energy conservation with the help of a energy level diagram? I read that due to two-photon absorption, a medium expected to be transparent would not be so, but if w1 = w1+w2-w2, doesn't it mean medium is anyways not transparent to w1 frequency?                      
tl;dr : I know that neither w1 nor w2 can cause the transition, but w1+w2 does. If so, how to understand the equality w1 = w1+w2-w2 ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on "... to add ... you need to multiply by two more fields ..."? Your third equation sets up a polarization oscillating at the frequency of one of the two photons present.  I could just as easily set up a polarization oscillating at the *other* frequency.

Comment: @garyp Equation 2 is more of a pedagogical step from Eq 1 (linear response) to the second expression of energy conservation in the last paragraph. Clearly, X(3)(0=w1-w1+w2-w2) doesn't favor either of the photons; they are both absorbed leaving no oscillation. But hopefully Eq 2 is helpful for understanding why that's a chi 3 process. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

The relation between the number of photons - or, equivalently, order of the electronic transitions - involved in a [TPA process](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0268-1242/26/8/083001/meta) (two) and the order of the corresponding nonlinear susceptibility (third) may be understood using the [optical theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_theorem). This theorem relates the imaginary part of an all-optical process of a given perturbation order $m$ with a process involving charge carriers with half the perturbation order, i.e. $m/2$. To apply this theorem it is important to consider that the order in perturbation theory to calculate the probability amplitude of an all-optical $\chi ^{(n)}$ process is $m=n+1$. Since in the case of TPA there are electronic transitions of the second order involved ($m/2=2$), it results from the optical theorem that the order of the nonlinear susceptibility is $n=m-1=3$, i.e. it is a $\chi ^{(3)}$ process.

Note also that in the case of processes involving only *virtual* electronic transitions the number of photons that take place in the process directly corresponds to the order of the nonlinear susceptibility. For instance, second harmonic generation (SHG) exploits a $\chi^{(2)}$ nonlinearity.

Answer (score 0):

I think Gilbert explained it very well but to help you with the intuition,a very rough and short answer: since we are saying "two photons" we are referring to **intensity** (number of photons). However, for example in a second-harmonic generation, we refer to square of the **electric field** not the square of intensity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/403421)

Answer (score 0):

As I learned from somewhere else, a non-linear process is of n-th order when n+1 waves are involved. In two photon absorption, 2 photons are absorbed and then 2 photons are emitted later, adding up to 4 light waves, which means it's a 3rd order non-linear process. By this criterion one can easily infer that three photon absorption is a fifth order non-linear process.

Answer (score -1):

Two photon absorption phenomena is characteristic of materials namely semiconductor, insulators. When bandgap energy $E_\mathrm{g}=\frac{\hbar\omega}{2\pi}$ is larger then a photon being incident, there is simultaneous absorption of two photons. And these materials actually exhibit third order nonlinearity

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the original question, which is why two-photon absorption must be thought of in terms of third-order linearity and not second-order nonlinearity.